# ggplot2 - merging two ggplots into one graph. strike zone and pitch

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two ggplots like these:

```
strike_zones <- data.frame(
  x1 = rep(-1.5:0.5, each = 3),
  x2 = rep(-0.5:1.5, each = 3),
  y1 = rep(1.5:3.5, 3),
  y2 = rep(2.5:4.5, 3),
  z = factor(c(7, 4, 1, 8, 5, 2, 9, 6, 3))
  )

 pitcher <- data.frame(
 px = c(1.5,2.4, 0, 2),
 pz = c(3,3,3,4.1)
 )

 # Plot example of PITCHf/x strike zone regions
 p <- ggplot() +
 xlim(-4, 4) + xlab("") +
 ylim(0, 6.8) + ylab("") +
 geom_rect(data = strike_zones,
        aes(xmin = x1, xmax = x2, ymin = y2, ymax = y1), color = "grey") +     theme_bw() + theme(legend.position = "none")

q <- ggplot(pitcher, aes(x=px,y=pz,color=description)) + geom_point(shape=1)
```

Basically I am trying to plot pitch location (px as x, and pz as y) over the strike zone. It won't let me and gives me message like this:

```
  Error in p + o : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

In addition: Warning message:
Incompatible methods ("+.gg", "Ops.data.frame") for "+"

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding whole q to plot p, just add the geometric object to plot p like this

```
p + geom_point(data = pitcher, aes(x= px, y =pz), shape = 1)
```